# 50035 Invalid Form Body - Application command names are unique

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a quick bot (with my limited knowledge of discord.js) that has a command to "mine bobux" which determines a random variable and tells the user how much bobux they "mined." After doing node deploy-commands.js (following discordjs.guide) powershell responds with

```
S[50035]: Invalid Form Body
1[APPLICATION_COMMANDS_DUPLICATE_NAME]: Application command names are unique
    at Q.runRequest (C:\Users\myname\Downloads\bobuxminer\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:7:581)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Q.queueRequest (C:\Users\myname\Downloads\bobuxminer\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:5:2942) {
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: { '1': [Object] },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'put',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/936299610002038784/guilds/399355403567366146/commands',
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [ae], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }
}
```

This is the command itself that I am trying to make.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('mine')
                                 .setDescription('Mines bobux'),
  async execute(interaction) {
    var bobuc = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    await interaction.reply(`You mined ${bobuc} bobux`);
  },
};
```

I've checked all my files and found no duplicate commands and do not know how to resolve this issue. If you need anything else, I will provide my other files.

Comment: That means you have multiple commands with the same name

Comment: @MrMythical I have only one command with the name mine

Comment: After removing all other instances of the command, it has registered. The question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all other instances of the command and only keep the command in the mine.js file.